Not all partitions lead Quadratic Variation of Brownian Motion converge to $T$ in $2^\text{nd}$ moment
We have to prove that $$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} E\left|\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left( \Delta w_{t_{i}^{n}} \right)^2  - T\right|^2 =0$$
Or that is Quadratic Variation of Brownian Motion converges to $T$ in $2^\text{nd}$ moment
So I have shown that
$$E\left|\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left( \Delta w_{t_{i}^{n}} \right)^2  - T\right|^2 = 2\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\Delta t_{i}^{n})^2$$
Now since these are partitions why cannot I fix a partition say $\Delta t_1^n \gt \delta \gt 0$ so that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}2\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\Delta t_{i}^{n})^2 \ne 0 $
The only explanation was that we are supposed to take finer partitions that is $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \Delta t_i^n =0 $ $\forall i$ but why?
